# play pause button not working properly

Tags: jquery

jquery:

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'play')
        $(this).attr('class', 'pause');
    else
        $(this).attr('class', 'play');
});

$('.play').on('click',function(){
    $('div').css({'background':'blue'}); 
});

$('.pause').on('click',function(){
    $('div').css({'background':'green'}); 
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eQdgk/)

It's changing the div color only once. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While registering the events, There is no possibility to have all the classes which you have specified, Because you are adding those classes at runtime. So you have to use `event-delegation` to hook the `click` event handler for those classes with `document` or its `nearest parent`.

Try,

```
$(document).on('click','.play',function(){
    $('div').css({'background':'blue'}); 
});

$(document).on('click','.pause',function(){
    $('div').css({'background':'green'}); 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eQdgk/5/)

Comment: .on() can even be chained, so we don't have to write `$(document)` again, but that's the preference of taste :P

Comment: @Holybreath I just answered in the way OP thinks. :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all , you need to delegate your event for dynamically added elements( since your chnaging the class here)... use `on`  **delegate it to closest static parent element present in the document rather than document itself for better performance** ...

and you don't need seperate click event for id selector.. you can add and remove respective class in there respective click event

try this

```
$(document).on('click','.play',function(){
  $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
  $('div').css({'background':'blue'}); 
});

$(document).on('click','.pause',function(){
   $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
  $('div').css({'background':'green'}); 
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/eQdgk/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Check your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eQdgk/1/

I have changed your javascript to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#toggle', function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('play')){
        $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');   
        $('div').css({'background':'blue'}); 
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');    
        $('div').css({'background':'green'}); 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use follow code

```
HTML

<span id="toggle" >toggle</span>
<div id='box' class="play"></div>
```

---

```
CSS

div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}

.play{
  background:blue
}
.stop{
  background:green
}
```

---

```
jQuery

$('#toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('#box').toggleClass('stop');
});
```